# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] system can't find the file specified

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, librosa

I used to load waveform file with librosa but failed

I tried to check the kernel.jason file to fix it

```
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import librosa.display
import IPython.display as ipd
%matplotlib inline

filepath = './audio_train/happy/'
filename = filepath + '00334.wav'

y, sr = librosa.load(filename, sr=None)
```

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

Comment: [Here][1] I got the solution to edit the python path into `<env_folder>\share\jupyter\kernels\python3\kernel.json` which in my case was pointing to the username that was different in the other machine

Answer (score 1):

i fix this problem by entering conda install -c conda-forge librosa at prompt

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y
pip install requirements.txt
```