# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while loading file using librosa

Tags: python, librosa

I am trying to load an audio file using Python's library librosa.

I have tried changing the path of the files. still the error persists. Even I tried another library sound file to read the audio file it worked well. Wondering what's the issue with librosa.

```
file = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.wav'))
data, samplerate = lb.load(file[0], sr=None)
```

Comment: Try `print(file[0])` before loading it, maybe it'll give you a clue.

Comment: it gives the correct path. means the desired one.

Comment: Please post the complete error message with stack trace. You will get a `FileNotFoundError` not only when the audio file is not found, but also when dependencies like FFmpeg are unavailable. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56246836/942774, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56235766/942774, and others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundError: \[WinError 2\] system can't find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235766/filenotfounderror-winerror-2-system-cant-find-the-file-specified)